# Compute arrival date given departure date and duration

Tags: algorithm, pascal

I am trying to make a program to calculate when train comes for a to b.
I have time when train leaves and the time it takes to travel to distance from a to b.
I need help a algorithm to find if that train bypasses 24 hours.
Like I got these times: Train leaves at 20:55, train ride time - 11:40.
The result should be 8:35, but how could I get it?

```
 program troleibusai;
 var xxx:integer ;
 f,g:text ;
 a:real;
 Begin
 Assign(F,'train_times'); 
 Reset(F);
 Assign(G,'results.txt');
 Rewrite(G);
 Read(F,left_hour);
 Read(F,left_minute);
 Read(F,ride_hour);
 Read(F,ride_minute);
```

Heres the code.

Comment: [code]program troleibusai;
var xxx:integer ;
f,g:text ;
a:real;
Begin
    Assign(F,'train_times');
    Reset(F);
    Assign(G,'results.txt');
    Rewrite(G);
    Read(F,left_hour);
Read(F,left_minute);
Read(F,ride_hour);
Read(F,ride_minute);

[/code]

Comment: Are you sure you need only an algorithm or is it the program? If it's code help you need, then you ought to state your Pascal version. Eg: freepascal

Comment: Showing your code in a comment is not the ideal thing. Please edit your question and insert the code in it.

Comment: yeah, it is free pascal. By the way, how can i add code?

Comment: @RimantasRadžiūnas EDIT your question and include code in it.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) and please format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the between functions in unit dateutils,

e.g. http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/dateutils/minutesbetween.html

Answer (score 1):

Calculate `left_hour * 60 + left_minute + ride_hour * 60 + ride_minute`
and get it `div 60` and `mod 60`